# Calculating HashMap overhead in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, data-structures, hashmap, overhead

Let's say I'm storing 1000 objects in a hashmap. This hashmap is extended to allow me to map three dimensional coordinates to the objects stored in it; the objects inside have a fixed size. The hash key is a long integer.

How would I go about figuring out (mathematically) the probable overhead for this structure?

1. Is it significant enough that, for instance, if the data inside is around 256mb that the overhead will matter?
2. Is there a reliable way (Aside from a profiler, which I've found are unreliable in some cases) to mathematically calculate what its overhead *should be*?

I'm not interested in the total size of the hashmap - only the *overhead* that using the hashmap will incur. For instance, if I have 10 ints they're 4 bytes a piece, so it's 40 bytes. If I stick them in an array, I get a constant overhead of 12 bytes - 8 for the object header, 4 for the length. If I put them in another structure (a TreeSet for instance) my overhead will not be constant because a tree needs nodes - so I might get an overhead expressed in terms of n where n is the number of items in the set.

A few things are obvious to me, which I'll give as my starting point here.

1. I will need to store at least 1000 longs. These are nullable types, so they're actually objects. I will assume therefore that the 8 byte long integer being used has an object header also of 8 bytes. I will add a factor of 16n.
2. I will need references to every object as well, which must exist whether or not the object has been recalled from the map and is being used; so that's an additional 8 bytes per object. We could factor it into the data size instead, but since the references are in the hashmap itself, I feel like it's best to make them part of the overhead. My logic is as follows: If I took all of the data out of the hashmap and stored it in variables, those n references would still exist in the hashmap, provided I didn't *remove* these data objects, which I won't be doing. The set of objects is constant, though they may be recycled with a different key.
3. The hashmap itself has an overhead of 8 bytes.
4. The hashmap *must* store the number of items inside (or so I think!) so that's 4 bytes.
5. I will suppose ignorantly that the hash keys are in an array, sorted by hash key order. That's 12 bytes for the array.
6. I will assume ignorantly as well that the objects are in a matching array, which it dereferences when it finds the key. I will guess another 12 bytes.

This gives me a polynomial equation: 36 + 24n

Thus I have a guess of 24036 bytes overhead for 1000 data objects using long keys. This is somewhat of an insignificant overhead, but my question for you is, what is the real overhead, just sitting there?

---

A secondary valid question is, how much does this vary from JVM to JVM? Is there any JVM independent way to figure it out? To exemplify what I mean, consider a JVM that only has 32bit object headers - when looking at arrays you might say, even though the size varies from JVM to JVM, it's a fair estimate that the overhead on an array would become 8 bytes instead of 12 in that case.

I'm assuming a fixed implementation of HashMap across the same version of Java.

---

I could try to read the source code or run profiling, this however may produce misleading results based on my JVM. I'm asking for your help - perhaps someone who knows - for some piece of info that we both don't already know about the situation. Thanks!

---

See the answer below, the actual estimate can be expressed as follows:

8 words per entry, plus 8 bytes for each long, plus 8 bytes for the hashmap object header.

In my present environment (32 bit OS) that makes 1 word = 4 bytes.

- 40n + 8 in a 32bit environment: ~ 40k for 1000 entries
- 72n + 8 in a 64bit environment: ~ 72k for 1000 entries.

So it seems to be under 100kbytes.

Comment: I would drop point 1 because I don't think the hashmap stores the actual keys. It computes their hash and uses this as an index in the hashmap(probably stored as an array) and I would add n * (size of the hash code) to your formula

Comment: Seems feasible. Still, that would suggest an array of some unknown size that must maintain 'sparseness' so there are no key collisions.

Comment: Doesn't Java's HashMap use separate chaining? I'm fairly certain you have to store a reference to the key.

Comment: @Razvan It stores the keys because collisions can happen.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()

Comment: @Will: Does the  java HashMap  promise a collision free implementation ?

Comment: So it does keep the keys. But how big is the array when you have 1000 items so that it can avoid collisions?

Comment: RiverC, Will: I frankly don't know whether the HashMap stores the keys or not, but the collisions issue is not an argument for convincing me that it stores the keys. Assume you have Long l1 containing x Long l2 containg y whose hashCode() mehtods return the same value, then you will certainly have a collision in java HashMap

Comment: What concerns me here is that this collision issue suggests a variable internal structure  - based on my knowledge of the general hash mapping data structure. For large lists of items this structure could be quite large - and does its size vary based on the data type you're using as a key?

Comment: @Razvan Indeed hash codes are not unique. In your example, equals() is called to distinguish the keys.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Of course HashMap stores the keys. How would it compare them to the one you pass as argument if it didn't store them? Read the javadoc: it's all explained there.

Comment: @JBNizet - which javadoc? The one for map, the one for hash, the one for hashmap, the one for... ???

Comment: The general contract is defined by the interface, Map. Collections in general, unless specified otherwise, use equals to compare objects. A Map considers that a key is in the map if it contains a key that is equals to the keyp passed as argument. Even if something other than equals is used (compareTo, for example, in case of a TreeMap) , it has to store the keys to be able to call the compareTo method. Moreover, Map has a keySet() method returning the keys, so obviously, it needs to store them.

Comment: Yes the keys are also stored. I was talking about a theoretical implementation :).
@RiverC: This two might be helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following [blog post](http://code-o-matic.blogspot.com/2012/02/updated-memory-cost-per-javaguava.html) provides some loose mathematics on the topic.
This [google code site](https://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures) provides a look at how these things are done.

Quoting the links in case of link rot:

```
This is the cheat-sheet I compiled.

To compute the cost of a single (key, value) entry:

    If you use HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap, the cost is 8 words (32 bytes)


 So, consider this example from the javadoc:

   LoadingCache graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(10000)
       .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader() {
             public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });


The cost of an Entry in this structure this is computed as follows:

    It's a Cache: +12 words
    It uses maximumSize(): +4 words
    It uses expiration: +4 words

Thus, each (key, value) entry would have a footprint of 20 words (thus 80 bytes in a 32bit VM, or 160 in a 64bit one). 

To estimate the overhead imposed in the garbage collector, one could count how many references (pointers) each entry introduces, which the garbage collector would have to traverse to compute object reachability. The same list again, this time only counting references:

    If you use HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap, the cost is 5 references
```

Comment: So, to clarify: for my straight hashmap, it would be 8 words (32bytes in 32bit, 64bytes in 64bit) per key/value pair, approximately. I would assume this doesn't include the size of the key itself nor the data itself.

Comment: Thank you for your straightforward answer! It also includes some extra information (kudos to the blog poster who explained the overhead on the GC as well, which I forgot about.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a program where you create all your objects and store them in a simple array. Measure the used memory (See [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)).

Then store them in a HashMap. Measure the used memory.

Subtract the first measured memory to the second used memory, and you have the overhead of the HashMap.

Comment: No... I could do this if I wished, but I'm asking for the math.

Comment: For the math, you need to know precisely how objects are stored in the map, know precisely how much a reference, an array etc. cost on your JVM, and do what you have done in your question. Read the source code of HashMap and the documentation of your JVM.

Comment: Both things I could do, but neither of which even necessarily answers the question. -- after all, my reading of the source code could be wrong, and obviously the documentation of *my* JVM may not apply to the JVM of someone else using my program.

Comment: This is why the best way is to measure, on both JVMs. A 64-bit JVM doesn't consume the same memory as a 32-bit JVM. If you don't want to do the math, and don't want to measure, what is left?

Comment: Because I need to know the actual calculation. Based on my first guess, the difference in JVM is immaterial - even double that memory usage doesn't mean anything. I need the math if someone has it, not 'rtfm'. -- consider that O(n^2) overhead would be significant, but O(n) would not, unless the constant was something large. Butting my head against my JVM to glean this information is pointless if someone actually knows what's going on internally. Do you?

Comment: The calculation is simple: check your JVM to see how much a reference costs, how much an int costs, how mush an array costs, etc., then add the memory used by all the references, arrays, ints, etc. used by the interla structure of the HashMap implementation that your JVM uses. A HashMap is basically an array storing linked lists of, hopefully, as few elements as possible (0 or 1 if everything is fine). It can't be O(n^2). It is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it significant enough that, for instance, if the data inside is around 256mb that the overhead will matter?

Definitely not. The overhead of 1000 objects in a HashMap isn't even worth worrying about in any event: if they are 256mb each in total, even less so. If the overhead was 256k, which it isn't, that would only be 1%. Not significant.

> 1. Is there a reliable way (Aside from a profiler, which I've found are unreliable in some cases) to mathematically calculate what its overhead should be?

Given my answer to (1) the question is moot.

Comment: Though I've received a reasonable way to estimate it - but thanks for your answer anyway!