# How much Heap memory my HashMap would occupy?

Tags: java, hashmap, heap-memory

If I have HashMap like below having 1000 entries inside, how much memory my HashMap will occupy on JAVA, 64 bit machine?

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String,int>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,int>>();
```

Please describe considering me novice programmer.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157363/how-to-calculate-hashmap-memory-usage-in-java) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565554/calculating-hashmap-overhead-in-java) is useful also